# Aws AuthenticationHandler

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am working on authenticating user on AWS Cognito android sdk but I am getting SRP error. I uncheck ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH, CUSTOM_AUTH_FLOW_ONLY, and USER_PASSWORD_AUTH and still getting the "SRP Error". Is there anything I am doing wrong. My code is below

```
   userPool = new CognitoUserPool(getApplicationContext(), "us-east- 
      2_UMicfarEa", "6q46s4k4jgvmliumcf4h4p94rs", 
      "t2dmr2ghna2l145qu4nst2gdr5actogeft7blr3eruv2yrvaye", Regions.US_EAST_2);

   user = userPool.getUser( userName);

   authenticateDetails = new Hashtable();
        authenticateDetails.put("username",userName);
        authenticateDetails.put("password", passWord);
        user = userPool.getUser( userName);



     AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession userSession, CognitoDevice 
         newDevice) {}
         @Override
         public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation 
         authenticationContinuation, String userId) { AuthenticationDetails 
         authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(userName, passWord, 
         authenticateDetails); authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);
         authenticationContinuation.continueTask();}
         @Override
         public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation 
         multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation) {
         multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation.setMfaCode(mfaVerificationCode);
         multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation.continueTask();}
         @Override
         public void authenticationChallenge(ChallengeContinuation continuation) {}
         @Override
         public void onFailure(Exception exception) {}
         };
     user.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);
```

Comment: what is your error ? your code is more a less same as example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-android-sdk.html, so it should work provided that client id and secret are correct.

Comment: not returning CognitoUserSession userSession. Do I need to check one of these ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH, CUSTOM_AUTH_FLOW_ONLY, and USER_PASSWORD_AUTH. Thanks